# Azure DevOps Pipines - Git Respository local directory location

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, devops

I have created a Pipeline in Azure DevOps and have associated a git repository.
It is cloned to my agent, but I can't get control over in which local directory the repository is cloned to. I am working with self hosted Agent.
The next task need to use a specific file in the repository to complete the task.

The last things tha should happen in the pipline, is push back changes made in the respository.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is WorkingDirectory, the local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. For example: c:\agent_work\1\s

[image]